# Cannot convert AzureStorageContext to IStorageContext

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to copy files from a Azure Blob Storage Container to the Azure file share (in the same Azure Storage Account).

When using Start-AzureStorageFileCopy or New-AzureStorageDirectory I get an error on the context parameters:

> Start-AzureStorageFileCopy : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot
>   convert the 
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of
>   type  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" to
>   type 
>   "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext".

```
$StorageAccountName = "myStorageAccount"
$StorageAccountKey = "FAKEbkasdw504jfja0jgldheeeffl03659d0ch259fv=="
$ContainerName = "myContainerName"
$ShareName = "myShareName"


Write-Output "Start moving folder content $($ContainerName) from storageaccount $($StorageAccountName) to file share $($ShareName)"

# Get 'context' of the source container
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext  -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
                                        -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey


# Loop through all blobs
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $StorageContext
foreach ($blob in $blobs)
{
    # Switch slashes because fileshare expects \ instead /
    $FilePath = $blob.name -replace '/','\'

    # Get folderpath to create new folders
    $FolderPath = Split-Path -Path $FilePath

    # If folder was found (not the case for files in the rooth) create it on the share
    # Todo: check if it exists
    if ($FolderPath.Length -gt 0)
    {
        # Create folder
        Write-Output "Create folder $($FolderPath) in fileshare"
        New-AzureStorageDirectory   -ShareName $ShareName            `
                                    -Path $FolderPath                `
                                    -Context $StorageContext.Context `
                                    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #Todo check if folder already exits
    }

    # Copy file from blob storage container to fileshare
    Write-Output "Copy file $($blob.name) to fileshare"
    Start-AzureStorageFileCopy  -SrcContainerName $ContainerName    `
                                -SrcBlobName $blob.name             `
                                -DestShareName $ShareName           `
                                -DestFilePath $FilePath             `
                                -Context $StorageContext.Context    `
                                -DestContext $StorageContext.Context     


    # Delete file from blob storage container
    Write-Output "Remove blob $($blob.name) from blob container"
    Remove-AzStorageBlob -Context $StorageContext -Blob $blob.name -Container $ContainerName
}
```

I tried adding **.Context** after the context parameters and it shows IStorageContext instead of AzureStorageContext, but got the same error
[image]

And the strange thing is that 3 weeks ago it worked without errors and now I got this error. Not sure what has changed in the meanwhile

Comment: Looks like a known issue when mixing `Az` and `Azure.Storage` command: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8265#issuecomment-453886907 - stick to one or the other

Comment: It looks like you're right! Thanks.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen          Since the  issue has been solved, could you please post the answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could not mix the new `Az` command with old `AzureRm` command together. And  you should note, not only the `Az.Storage` and `Azure.Storage` module, but also other modules, they give different errors. I have encountered this situation several times.

So in your case, reopen a new powershell session, use [`Start-AzStorageFileCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/start-azstoragefilecopy?view=azps-3.5.0) and [`New-AzStorageDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragedirectory?view=azps-3.5.0) instead of the `Start-AzureStorageFileCopy` and  `New-AzureStorageDirectory`.

Or if you don't want to change the script, you could reopen a new powershell session,  run [`Enable-AzureRmAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-3.5.0) before all your commands, it will also work.